# Tesseract image_to_string is empty

Tags: image-processing, python-imaging-library, ocr, tesseract

I have a simple text in an image `image_ball.png`. Usually OCR of Tesseract works well, but for this certain image it returns always an empty string.
[image: image_ball.png]

```
In [1]: from PIL import Image

In [2]: from pytesseract import image_to_string

In [3]: img = Image.open("image_ball.png")

In [4]: image_to_string(img)
Out[5]: u''
```

I could not find a workaround up-to-now.
How could I figure out what is going wrong with this image?

The versions are:

```
In [6]: import PIL

In [7]: PIL.__version__
Out[7]: '4.0.0'


$ tesseract -v
tesseract 4.0.0
 leptonica-1.77.0
  libgif 5.1.4 : libjpeg 9c : libpng 1.6.36 : libtiff 4.0.10 : zlib 1.2.11 : libwebp 1.0.2 : libopenjp2 2.3.0
 Found AVX2
 Found AVX
 Found SSE
```

**EDIT**

I tried also to convert the image to black/white. But it is still not recognized.

```
In [6]: image = img.convert('L') 

In [7]: image_to_string(image)
Out[8]: u''
```

**EDIT 2**

Single characters seem also to be a problem to Tesseract. Dilating or eroding the image seems not to help: `image_1.png`
[image: image_1.png]

Comment: Try converting your input image to binary ( black text on white background )

Comment: @DmitriiZ. Thank you for your answer. But it still is not recognised.. could you look at the edit? Am I missing something?

Comment: You can also try dilating image. `image = cv2.imread("Ball.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) cv2.dilate(image, (5, 5), image)` gives me `Ball` as output.

Comment: @DmitriiZ. Great! That works! Thank you very much! You could post an answer for me accepting it.. Could you also help me out with the image `image_1.png` in Edit 2?

Comment: Running the same code (with dilation) on your image gives me `1` as output if I set psm to 7.

Comment: You can read more about *page segmentation mode* [here](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Command-Line-Usage#tesseract---help-extra)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dilating image gives you the desired output.

```
image = cv2.imread("Ball.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) 
cv2.dilate(image, (5, 5), image)
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(image, config='--psm 7'))
```

> Ball

Comment: With `print(pytesseract.image_to_string(image, config='--psm 7'))` it works great!

Comment: I face the following error: `TypeError: 'config' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`, how can I fix it?

Comment: To expand a bit on that: The `--psm` argument controls the segmentation mode. `--psm 7` treats the image as a single line of text, which works well with this example. Call `tesseract --help-extra` to get an overview over all modes